# Populating the dropdown on the basis of selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have four drop down and each drop down having corresponding Id's. I want to hide and show second drop down on the basis of selected value from drop down1.

Update:

For example, on the selection of `M` I want to hide `<div>` having `id` "c"

```
<div id="b" class="span-6 ">
 <select>
   <option value="F">F</option>
   <option value="M">M</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="c" class="span-6 ">
   <select>
     <option value="S">S</option>
     <option value="M">M</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: don't hesitate to share with us what you tried so far, we'll be happy to help you correcting the errors ;)

Comment: 1) What you're describing is called "conditional logic" 2) post your code!

Comment: yes some thing like that but in drop down my value is just like yes or no. on the basis of selection i want to hide and show another div thats it..

Comment: this is my code:on the selection of M i want to hide div c ..this is my scenario..<div id="b" class="span-6 "> <select> <option value="F">F</option> <option value="M">M</option> </select> </div> <div id="c" class="span-6 "> <select> <option value="S">S</option> <option value="M">M</option> </select> </div>

Comment: can any one guide me what i m doing ...one the selected drop down value i need to call that function

Comment: @sam140 code dumps are really *unreadable* in comments... next time, please [edit] the question and update the information there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something along the following:

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  $(this).next("select").toggleClass("hidden", this.value == "no")
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
<select class="hidden">
  <option></option>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
<select class="hidden">
  <option></option>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
```

---

Updated answer according to comments:

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  $(this).parent().next().toggleClass("hidden", this.value == "M")
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="b" class="span-6 ">
  <select>
    <option value="F">F</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="c" class="span-6 ">
  <select>
    <option value="S">S</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Reference:

- [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent)
- [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next)
- [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass)
- [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: on the selection of M i want to hide div c ..this is my scenario..<div id="b" class="span-6 "> <select> <option value="F">F</option> <option value="M">M</option> </select> </div> <div id="c" class="span-6 "> <select> <option value="S">S</option> <option value="M">M</option> </select> </div>

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this and repeat the pattern for every select you want.

**HTML**

```
<select id="slc1">
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>

<select id="slc2" style="display: none">
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$( "#slc1" ).change(function () {
    value = $("#slc1").val();
    if ( value === '0' ) $( "#slc2" ).hide();
    else if (value === '1') $( "#slc2" ).show();
});
```

Comment: on the selection of M i want to hide div c ..this is my scenario..<div id="b" class="span-6 ">
<select>
<option value="F">F</option>
<option value="M">M</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="c" class="span-6 ">
<select>
<option value="S">S</option>
<option value="M">M</option>
</select>
</div>